# Nonstandard models of PA

Tags: arithmetic, peano-axioms

Reading The Incompleteness Phenomenon, by Goldstern and Judah, they show there are nonstandard models of PA by adding a constant greater than any natural number.  They then show that any countable model consists of the standard naturals followed by a dense linear order of copies of the integers (though we can't find the origin in any of these copies).  The demonstration relies on the fact that $\forall a,b [a\lt b\implies \exists c (c+c=a+b \vee c+c=a+S(b))]$ and that every number except $0$ has a predecessor.  There is no mention of multiplication in the argument, so we could delete the two multiplication axioms from PA and get the same restriction on the set of models.  Does multiplication not restrict the models of PA in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've heavily edited my original answer. The answer below is really two separate answers, each of which appeals to a different kind of intuition. The first is just about the very broad nature of the question, the idea being that the models-of-arithmetic language just makes things feel mysterious when they really aren't; the second answer goes into more detail, but may be less comprehensible until the first is read.

---

### An algebraic take

At its core, here's what's going on:

- We have three "big classes" $X,Y,Z$ with three distinguished subclasses $A\subseteq X,B\subseteq Y,$ and $C\subseteq Z$. We also have "forgetful" maps $f:X\rightarrow Z$, $g:Y\rightarrow Z$, and $h:X\rightarrow Y$.
- We're told that $f[A]=g[B]=C$, and that $h[A]\subseteq B$. However, despite this we can't figure out much about the relationship between $A$ and $B$. *(Perhaps it would be more appropriate to say that we can't from this alone figure out much about the relationship between $A$ and $h^{-1}[B]$ or about the relationship between $B$ and $h[A]$.)*

Specifically, $X,Y,$ and $Z$ are the classes of ordered semirings, ordered monoids, and linear orders respectively; $A,B$, and $C$ are the classes of countable models of $\mathsf{PA}$, countable models of Presburger arithmetic $\mathsf{Pres}$, and linear orders isomorphic to either $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{Z}\cdot\mathbb{Q}$ respectively; and $f,g,$ and $h$ are the "underlying order of an ordered ring," "underlying order of an ordered monoid," and "underlying ordered monoid of an ordered ring" constructions, respectively. And indeed the relationship between $A$ and $B$ is extremely complicated, no matter how you cut it.

In particular, the answer to your question *(rephrased for clarity)*

> Does multiplication [...] restrict the models of PA in any way?

is **it most certainly does**, and we can see this purely combinatorially as the fact that $A$ is "much smaller than" (and more importantly, much more *complicated* than) $h^{-1}[B]$.

---

### A more logic-y flavor

We have to distinguish between a model and one of its *reducts*. The key passage is:

> They then show that any countable model consists of the standard naturals followed by a dense linear order of copies of the integers

That's not quite true! Rather, **the underlying linear order of** a countable nonstandard model of $\mathsf{PA}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{Z}\cdot\mathbb{Q}$. But a model of $\mathsf{PA}$ is much more than just a linear order, and we can't recover that additional structure from the order alone.

For example, let $M$ be a countable nonstandard model of $\mathsf{PA}+Con(\mathsf{PA})$ and let $N$ be a countable (necessarily nonstandard) model of $\mathsf{PA}+\neg Con(\mathsf{PA})$. The "$\{<\}$-reducts" of $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic, but $M$ and $N$ themselves aren't even elementarily equivalent.

So all that is true is that $\mathsf{PA}$ and Presburger arithmetic each have the same *ordertypes of* countable models. But this is a very weak fact. In particular, it doesn't rule out $(i)$ the existence of countable models of Presburger arithmetic which cannot be expanded to models of $\mathsf{PA}$ or $(ii)$ the existence of countable models of Presburger arithmetic which can be expanded to models of $\mathsf{PA}$ in multiple distinct - even non-isomorphic - ways.

We can prove that $(i)$ holds via computability theory. Presburger arithmetic has computable nonstandard models (e.g. take the $\{+\}$-reduct of the set of polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ with nonnegative leading coefficient and constant term in $\mathbb{Z}$). But the $\{+\}$-reduct of a $\mathsf{PA}$-model can never be computable, by [Tennenbaum's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum%27s_theorem) (note that this uses the stronger version of the theorem).

I don't immediately see how to show that $(ii)$ holds, but if memory serves it does; I'll add the argument (or counter-argument, if I'm wrong) when I find it.

Comment: I think they support $ii$ but in different language.  They say there are uncountably many nonisomorphic countable models of PA, basing that on whether there is a number divisible by any subset of the primes in the model.  As there are only countably many numbers in the model and each is divisible by a countable subset of the primes, the union of all the subsets is countable.  They don't show that any (or an uncountable number of) subsets of the primes leads to a model.  Clearly any model must accommodate all finite subsets of the primes, because there is a standard natural they divide.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: To be precise: yes, there are continuum-many countable models of $\mathsf{PA}$ (and Presburger arithmetic for that matter) up to isomorphism, but what does that have to do with $(ii)$?

Comment: They are making the point that it is hard to get a handle on the nonstandard numbers.  Each standard number is only divisible by a finite number of primes, but we can't express this in first order logic, so nonstandard numbers can be divisible by an infinite subset of the primes.  Still, as there are countably many nonstandard numbers, most subsets of the primes will not divide any of them.  It appears they claim without justification that there is a model in which there is a number that any subset of the primes divides.  I hadn't noticed the hole until now.  Maybe this does not apply to $ii$

Comment: @RossMillikan There is indeed a nonstandard model $N$ of $\mathsf{PA}$ such that for every set $X$ of primes there is some $n\in N$ such that the standard primes dividing $n$ are exactly those in $X$ - it's just that such an $N$ can't be countable. (Incidentally, the ordertypes of uncountable models of $\mathsf{PA}$ are much more interesting.)

Comment: It sounds like what you are saying is they have given a requirement for countable nonstandard models, but have not given a definition of one that satisfies all of PA and that more models will satisfy Presburger arithmetic than all of PA.  That makes sense to me.  I would be interested in a reference for reading to go further.

Comment: @RossMillikan I've fixed an annoying error: the structure I claimed was a computable nonstandard model of Presburger arithmetic was **not** in fact a model of Presburger arithmetic *(e.g. it didn't satisfy $\forall x\exists y(x=y+y\vee x=y+y+1)$)*. As to a reference, the standard text is [Kaye's book](https://www.amazon.com/Models-Peano-Arithmetic-Oxford-Guides/dp/019853213X). Re: the overall question, it may help demystify things to just observe that this is an example of general behavior of forgetful functors *(e.g. very different classes of rings can have the same sets of additive groups)*.

Comment: @RossMillikan I've edited my answer to be hopefully clearer; let me know if this made things worse instead.

Comment: you have made things worse by \$190, the price of Kaye's book.  Yes, the answer is quite clear.  When I took college math (decades ago) I never heard the term category theory. I have seen it here on stackexchange, but it always seemed peripheral.